# ContentControl set type of displayed control from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf

I got custom wizard control, that used in different projects.
As example page4 used in one project, and another project use only page 1 and 2.
Is there any way to make viewModel provide type of control or something like that, to make `contentcontrol` use generic pages and show proper controls?

To make it clear, i dont want hardcode controls related to different projects, but decide witch control to show dynamically.

```
...
<ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding CurrentPage}">
            <ContentControl.Resources>   
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModelControls:WizardPage1ViewModel}">
                        <viewModelControls:WizardPage1Control/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModelControls:WizardPage2ViewModel}">
                        <viewModelControls:WizardPage2Control/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModelControls:WizardPage3ViewModel}">
                        <viewModelControls:WizardPage3Control/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModelControls:WizardPage4ViewModel}">
                        <viewModelControls:WizardPage4Control/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                     ...
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ContentControl.Resources>
        </ContentControl>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you the right way, you want to have one Window,
which hosts different controls while being in a specifc state?

So if, for Example, a button Login is pressed, you want to switch to another window with other controls?

I would make DataTemplates for the controls like you did:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="ShowLoginView">
     <local:LoginView />
  </DataTemplate>

  <DataTemplate x:Key="ShowEditView">
     <local:EditView />
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

And set a trigger to the contentcontrol:

```
<Style x:Key="ContentControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
  <Style.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=SessionState}" Value="0">
       <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ShowLoginView}"/>
     </DataTrigger/>

     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=SessionState}" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource ShowEditView}"/>
     <DataTrigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Then simply add the style to the contentcontrol:

SessionState has to be a shared resource (in App.xaml).
Now you can change the Window/UserControl by simply calling:

```
if(Application.Current != null && Application.Current is App)
{
   (Application.Current as App).SessionState = 0; // Login-Control
   //or
   (Application.Current as App).SessionState = 1; // Edit-Control
}
```

**Note**:
Don't forget to add the NotifyPropertyChanged to SessionState, otherwise the binding won't work.

Comment: Safe casts are useless if you don't check for *null*. Either check for *null* or use a normal cast (people will just copy/paste this code, be sure to apply best practices).

Comment: Best is something like this:

```
var application = Application.Current as App;
if (application != null)
{
    application.SessionState = 0;
    application.SessionState = 1;
}
```

Comment: This would be another possibility. Thanks for your advice. I think, I'll stay with the other one though. I think that doesn't make a big difference.